# clang ARM neon support

Tags: arm, clang, neon

I just cross-compiled the clang compiler for ARM on my x86 machine with instructions from here. I am trying to compile a c code containing NEON intrinsics with clang compiler. It is giving error, (which i do not encounter with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

`$ clang -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=soft -integrated-as test.c -o test
    In file included from test.c:2:
/home/junaid/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.2/include/arm_neon.h:28:2: error: 
      "NEON support not enabled"`

The line test.c:2 is #include arm_neon.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be the `-mfloat-abi=soft`. I'm surprised that works for you with an arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain.

For Neon support you will want to be targetting either the softfp, or hard float ABI, with either `-mfloat-abi=softfp` or `-mfloat-abi=hard`